# returning vs currval postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

I perform the following query:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, email, password, gender) 
VALUES (nextval('seq_user_id'), $2, $3, $4)
```

then:

```
INSERT INTO images (id, data, filesize, filename, user_id) 
VALUES (nextval($1), $2, $3, $4, currval('seq_user_id'));
```

I can do the same thing with `RETURNING id AS user_id` and then pass it into the next query, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste. Both solutions are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `RETURNING`, because the same approach works with multi-valued results.

You can only use `currval` when you only have a single result row.

Additionally, I'm not convinced that the evaluation order between `nextval` and `currval` is guaranteed when they appear in the same `VALUES` clause. So it's going to be safer to fetch the value in `RETURNING` and feed it as a parameter to the next query.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that currval() and nextval() in that clause refer to different indexes